# Println statements not printing

Tags: java, arrays, string, logging, output

I have three files in one project and I can't seem to make the println statements in my main class print! Help?

First file:

```
package chapter2;

public class UseStringLog
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    StringLogInterface log;
    log = new ArrayStringLog("Example Use");
    log.insert("Elvis");
    log.insert("King Louis XII");
    log.insert("Captain Kirk");
    System.out.println(log);
    System.out.println("The size of the log is " + log.size());
    System.out.println("Elvis is in the log: " + log.contains("Elvis"));
    System.out.println("Santa is in the log: " + log.contains("Santa"));
    }
}
```

Second file:

```
package chapter2;

public interface StringLogInterface
{
  void insert(String element);
  boolean isFull();
  int size();
  boolean contains(String element);
  void clear();
  String getName();
  String toString();
}
```

Third file:

```
package chapter2;

public class ArrayStringLog implements StringLogInterface
{
  protected String name;              
  protected String[] log;             
  protected int lastIndex = -1;       

  public ArrayStringLog(String name, int maxSize)
  {
    log = new String[maxSize];
    this.name = name;
  }

  public ArrayStringLog(String name) 
  {
    log = new String[100];
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void insert(String element)
  {      
    lastIndex++;
    log[lastIndex] = element;
  }

  public boolean isFull()
  {              
    if (lastIndex == (log.length - 1)) 
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public int size()
  {
    return (lastIndex + 1);
  }

  public boolean contains(String element)
  {                 
    int location = 0;
    while (location <= lastIndex) 
    {
      if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(log[location]))  // if they match
        return true;
      else
        location++;
    }
   return false;
  }

  public void clear()
  {                  
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
      log[i] = null;
    lastIndex = -1;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String logString = "Log: " + name + "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
      logString = logString + (i+1) + ". " + log[i] + "\n";

    return logString;
  }
}
```

I run each and all of them have a successful build but there is just no output!

Comment: How do you run your program? And what is the output you get?

Comment: You arent getting *any* output at all? Not even the hard coded strings? Also, where are you running this? Eclipse? Command line? Another IDE?

Comment: I use NetBeans. I run it and all I get is a BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: @KTF for me it works just fine on [*Netbeans too*](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6086504/Untitled.png) you must be missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine!

**OUTPUT:**

```
Log: Example Use

1. Elvis
2. King Louis XII
3. Captain Kirk

The size of the log is 3
Elvis is in the log: true
Santa is in the log: false
```

Things to check:

- compilation errors (you didn't include a certain class in the package, forgot an "import" etc)
- try to call `System.out.println("test);` in the first line of main() - see that it prints
- run on the code with a debugger

Comment: @tbodt you don't have to "make" it work - it works "as is" without any modifications!

Comment: @tbodt I don't understand your question: copy the code "as is" into files with relevant names (class/interface names .java) compile and run!

Answer (score 0):

That code works perfectly, and there is nothing wrong with it whatsoever. So, there must be something wrong with the way you run the code. Here's a checklist:

- Make sure you are running the right class file.
- If you are using an IDE, make sure you know how to use it.
- If you got through chapter 1 of your book, you probably managed to run the programs in there. Try the same method.

And finally, last but not least:

- Have your IQ checked. You are advised to stay away from java coding if it is less than 150. `:-)`

Comment: So, I get it that you finally understood how to run it ? :)